# R: debugging "undefined columns selected"

Tags: r, debugging

When working with R, one of the most common errors is using a non-existent column:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , c(id, nbdays, study, methods)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

For simple code, this is easy to fix, but for complex code and dataframes having hundreds of columns, identifying the offending column can quickly become a nightmare.

Is there a way to figure out which columns are missing?

Comment: Please show a small rperoducible example.  You can do `intersect(names(data), c("id", "nbdays", "study", "methods"))` or to find out missing columns `setdiff`

Comment: @akrun I'm asking for a generic solution. It's not always obvious to see what columns are being accessed, especially in deeply nested code.

Comment: Without knowing what your code, example etc. we can only provide answers based on guesses.  How did you get this error?  Is it by rbinding the datasets.  All of these info are missing.  It could be general, but you also stated that it is based on a complex code, so I am not sure

Answer (score 2):

We can do `intersect` to find the intersecting columns

```
intersect(names(data), c("id", "nbdays", "study", "methods"))
```

Or with `setdiff` to find the columns not be found

```
setdiff(names(data), c("id", "nbdays", "study", "methods"))
```

Comment: This assumes you know what columns are being accessed. In deeply nested functions, it can be hard to know.

Comment: @static_rtti  But your question was also not having any reproducible example and showed only an error

Comment: Yes, it's a general question so it can't be reduced to a single reproducible example. If you don't immediately understand what this is about, you probably haven't experienced the problem yourself.

Comment: @static_rtti  Probably, but most of the questions show a small reproducible example and expected output